# Dynamic Lightning Input Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic, design-attributes

I have a custom Lightning component which is a simple input form with the Contact fields(required). Obviously the controller class has an **insert** statement for the Contact sObject.

Is there a way I can create an input component that is not specific to any sObject, and have a Property setup(**Design** file in the Aura definition bundle) that says: `<design:attribute name="objectAPIName" label="sObject"/>` which I can assign any sObject I wanted, and the form should dynamically show the required fields specific to the provided sObject?

Controller to fetch all the fields(Dynamically):

```
@AUraEnabled
public static List<String> dynamicField(String ObjectName){

    String objName = ObjectName;
    Schema.SObjectType t = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName);
    SObject s = t.newSObject();

    DescribeSObjectResult describeResultPP = s.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
    List<String> fieldNamesPP = new List<String>( describeResultPP.fields.getMap().keySet() );

    System.debug('Field attributes: ' +fieldNamesPP);

    return fieldNamesPP;
}
```

How can I make use of these fields to populate on the input form? My concern is, I get all the fields of that specific sObject, how can I only display/show required fields to fill in? Also I am not even sure how I can display those on a Lightning.cmp file.

Comment: This is absolutely possible, but is a significant amount of work. I have done something similar but will need to see if I can get permission to share any source code for it since it was a part of an ISV project. If not I can at least share the overall architecture that was used to implement this in a lightning component.

Comment: @dsharrison, can you create a small demo and share the code, This looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Let me share an overall architecture that I used to accomplish a very similar problem. The first thing I did was to create an apex class `FieldDetail` to model a field describe with `@AuraEnabled` get methods for all relevant information like label, data type, etc. Next, an `inputField` component was created to consume that information and conditionally render a specific component using `$A.createComponent()` depending on the data type. Note that we used both `lightning` namespaced components as well as some components from the [strike](http://www.lightningstrike.io/) project. Once we had an input that could render itself for a `FieldDetail`, it was simply a task of adding a top level controller that would retrieve a list of `FieldDetail` objects and iterating over them to render a `c:inputField` component for each field. In your case that controller may have a method signature similar to:

```
@auraEnabled
public static List<FieldDetail> getRequiredFieldDetails(String sObjectName)
```

You could then pass the `sObjectName` parameter from either a design attribute or using one of the built in [interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_force_hassobjectname.htm) like `force:hasSObjectName` and use object and field describes to build your list of `FieldDetail` objects.

**== Code Sample Update ==**

The following class represents the details for a specific field and can be returned from an `@AuraEnabled` method to be consumed in Lightning.

```
/**
 *  SObjectFieldDetail object provides information of an SObject Field for
 *  thge lightning context.
 */
public with sharing class SObjectFieldDetail {

  private SObject record { get; set; }

  private Schema.SObjectField field { get; set; }

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  public SObjectFieldDetail(SObject record, Schema.SObjectField field) {
    this.record = record;
    this.field = field;
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    String value of the DisplayType of the field
   */
  public String getType() {
    Schema.DisplayType dataType = field.getDescribe().getType();
    return String.valueOf(dataType);
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Label of the field
   */
  public String getLabel() {
    return field.getDescribe().getLabel();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Returns true if the field is html formatted. (Rich Text)
   *             URL Fields return false
   */
  public Boolean getIsHtmlFormatted() {
    return field.getDescribe().isHtmlFormatted();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    True, if current user has read access.
   */
  public Boolean getHasReadAccess() {
    return field.getDescribe().isAccessible();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    True, if current user has write access.
   */
  public Boolean getHasEditAccess() {
    return field.getDescribe().isCreateable();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Returns field name
   */
  public String getFieldName() {
    return field.getDescribe().getName();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Returns local field name
   */
  public String getFieldLocalName() {
    return field.getDescribe().getLocalName();
  }
  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    If the field type is picklist, returns List of the label of all picklist options.
   *             Else, returns empty list.
   */
  public List<String> getAllPicklistOptions() {
    List<String> picklistOptions = new List<String>();
    if(getType() == 'PICKLIST'){
      List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = field.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
      for(Schema.PicklistEntry picklistEntry : picklistValues){
        picklistOptions.add(picklistEntry.getLabel());
      }
    }
    return picklistOptions;
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    If the field type is picklist, returns List of the label of active picklist options.
   *             Else, returns empty list.
   */
  public List<String> getPicklistOptions() {
    List<String> picklistOptions = new List<String>();
    if(getType() == 'PICKLIST'){
      List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = field.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
      for(Schema.PicklistEntry picklistEntry : picklistValues){
        if(picklistEntry.isActive()){
          picklistOptions.add(picklistEntry.getLabel());
        }
      }
    }
    return picklistOptions;
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    If the field type is picklist, returns List of the label of active picklist options.
   *             Else, returns empty list.
   */
  public String getDefaultPicklistOption() {
    if(getType() == 'PICKLIST'){
      return String.valueOf(field.getDescribe().getDefaultValue());
    }
    return null;
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Current value of the field
   */
  public Object getCurrentValue() {
    if(getHasReadAccess()){
      return record.get(field);
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    String value of the DisplayType of the field
   */
  public String getSObjectName() {
    return record.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    String value of the DisplayType of the field
   */
  public String getSObjectLocalName() {
    return record.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getLocalName();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Current max length of field
   */
  public Integer getFieldLength() {
    return field.getDescribe().getLength();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Current max length of field
   */
  public Integer getFieldPrecision() {
    return field.getDescribe().getPrecision();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Current max number of digits of field
   */
  public Integer getFieldDigits() {
    return field.getDescribe().getDigits();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Current max number of digits of field right of decimal
   */
  public Integer getFieldScale() {
    return field.getDescribe().getScale();
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Current max number of digits of field right of decimal
   */
  public Decimal getStep() {
    Decimal step = 1;

    for(Integer i = 0; i < getFieldScale(); i++){
      step = step / 10;
    }
    return step;
  }

  @auraEnabled
  /**
   * @returns    Current max number of digits of field right of decimal
   */
  public Decimal getMax() {
    Integer count = getFieldPrecision() - getFieldScale();
    String str = '';

    for(Integer i = 0; i < count; i++){
      str = str + '9';
    }
    if(getFieldScale() > 0){
      str = str + '.';
      for(Integer i = 0; i < getFieldScale(); i++){
        str = str + '9';
      }
    }
    if(str.length() > 0){
      return Decimal.valueOf(str);
    }
    else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

You can then construct instances of this class by passing in a record (this could be a new record like `new Contact()` and a list of fields. If you wanted all required fields, you use code similar to

```
List<Schema.SObjectField> allContactFields = Schema.Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values();
List<Schema.SObjectField> requiredContactFields = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();

for(Schema.SObjectField field : allContactFields) {
    if(field.getDescribe().isCreateable() && !field.getDescribe().isNillable() && !field.getDescribe().isDefaultedOnCreate()) {
        requiredContactFields.add(field);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented a method like you mentioned **FieldDetail**, which I have added in my question(`dynamicField`). It does return all the fields from whatever sObject we pass via **Design** attribute. But my main question is, how can I differentiate different sObject fields when I iterate **fieldNamesPP** in the Lightning component (.cmp) file? I have no clue to how to render those fields on the input form. Also, if I would only want fields that are **Required**, how to extract those from the list: **fieldNamesPP**. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your method is returning a String which is the field name. The major difference is that in my example I am returning a FieldDetail which has all information from the DescribeFieldResult in it (such as whether or not the field is required).

Comment: Can you help me with how to retrieve the DataType, Required and Length of all the fields for a given sObject (via my code)?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. Yes I can, let me put together a gist.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. I added some sample code directly to my answer.

Comment: thanks! I will definitely try your approach and keep you posted.